# Extract full attribute types from a java file

Tags: java, parsing, qdox

So i need to extract the types of attributes from java files. I am currently using the parser qdox to do this. It works fine for the most part.

The problem is that when I have attributes that have a type like this `List<String>` I need to get the full name of `String` i.e `java.lang.String`.

But it seems that qdox can´t extract the full name of the generic typ. Is there any way to get it?

Answer (score 1):

Generics are not preserved in the runtime due to [Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

You can inspect every element in the `List` but the `<String>` part of the type is not accessible for running program.